# incongruences between F-stats in the R cancor package

Tags: r, p-value, canonical-correlation

I'm using the R package candisc to perform canonical correlations.

Since my dataset has missing values (only 36 rows without any NAs out of 88 rows total), I have two options:

1. I can use the raw dataset as is and run cancor(..., use = "complete.obs",...)
2. I can delete rows with missing values in the dataset and then simply run cancor.

The canonical correlations and the loadings given by the two methods are exactly the same, but the p-values differ vastly. Essentially the p-values when using the raw dataset (case 1) are way way way smaller than those in case 2.

case 1:

```
     CanR LR test stat approx F numDF  denDF   Pr(> F)    
1 0.89079      0.01259   4.3816    96 208.52 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

case 2:

```
     CanR LR test stat approx F numDF  denDF Pr(> F)
1 0.89079      0.01259  0.71887    96 34.210  0.8926
```

The fact that the approximate F-stat in the second case is very close to (36/88)^2 smaller than in the first case makes me suspect a problem in the computation of the p-values when using the raw dataset.
However, since I can't seem to find where and how p-values are computed in the package, I remain confused.